# Is it possible to use prop-types to typeCheck regular Object, Function parameters and return value?

Tags: javascript, react-proptypes

Is it possible to use prop-types to typeCheck regular Object, Function parameters and return value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you are talking about using the [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) package outside of a React application. If that is the case - the answer is yes, but there are limitations.

To achieve this you need to explicitly call the `PropTypes.checkPropTypes` function. This usage is described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types#proptypescheckproptypes).

To check an object's shape you can use the `shapeOf()` function. When it comes to functions however, there is no good way I am afraid to check it's parameters or return value. There are several closed issues on the `prop-types` GitHub repository indicating that this is better suited for a type checking system such as [Flow](https://flow.org/) or [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). If you have a very simple setup or you are just getting into the JS ecosystem, I would advise you go with Flow as it is easier to inject into an existing project and can be adopted incrementally.

I hope this helps and answers your question.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried Flow, but Flow just typeCheck at compile time, so it will make sure that your code never assign a String where you expect a Number. But once you run the app, you can assign. You have no warning message, the app just behave abnormally, all your === and !== just fail silently and it take time to find the problem. I think it is a limitation. I prefer run time type check if I have to choose.

Comment: The main advantage of Flow is its IDE aspects. But I think with Jest and PropTypes you can successfully work without Flow.